# how to determine time complexity of algorithms with phases

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization

given an algorithm has two phase.one is initialization,that takes time O(n^2) and the other phase is the main computation that takes O(nlogn).then what will be the complexity of overall algorithm..???will it be max of two or something like O(n^2logn).best possible description will be

Answer (score 0):

[Its the maximum.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Sum)

You can find a proof for this in most algoritms books but its also an interesting exescise to try to prove it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the complexity as O(n² + n Log n), but as the first term dominates the other (grows faster), just O(n²).

Answer (score 0):

I'll just extend @Yves Daoust answer little bit with the following:

```
O(n² + n Log n) = 
  = O(n² * [1 + Log(n) / n]) = 
  ... (Log(n) / n) → 0, when n→∞ ...
  = O(n² * [1 + 0]) 
  = O(n²)
```